# How to access the water pump area of my dryer?

Tags: dryer

My dryer won't run because of a water issue (the water drop light comes on).

This dryer has a second lint catcher on the bottom that is near the water pump chamber. Behind this lint catcher there is a bunch of damp lint in a metal grate. Here's a picture:

[image]

So, my idea is to clean that area out and see if it fixes the issue. I have taken the top and both sides of the dryer off. Here is the side with the water pump chamber which is right behind the above picture:

[image]

You see that dark grey box under that black tube, that's what I think I need to get into. Here is the other side:

[image]

What is the best way to get into that dark grey water pump area? Do I need to take the rest of the dryer apart? It seems like I might be able to just unscrew the screws on top of the dark grey box and take the lid off but I'm not sure if I'll have room to operate. Here's the dryer info:

[image]